# ggplot2: customize x-axis by adding an asterisk to some of the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the built in R dataset `ToothGrowth`

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose,y=len,colour=supp)) +
  geom_point()
```

Is there a way to add an asterisk to some of the x-axis labels? For instance 1.0 and 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose,y=len,colour=supp)) +
    geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, 2, 0.5),
                                      ,labels = c("0.5","1*","1.5", "2*"))
```

[image]